# Transparent_hugepage - Disabling for memsql

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, singlestore, huge-pages

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS for memsql. I have tried to disable transparent_hugepage by adding line to grub

I have change the

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0" "transparent_hugepage=never"
```

Then I execute  sudo update-grub in the shell. and below error has thrown

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: transparent_hugepage=never: not found
```

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0 transparent_hugepage=never"
```